# Masking Password using checkbox in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, textbox

I have a Text box (PinEntry) and a Check box. The Check box will mask the password when checked. However, it only masks once. I understand the logic of the first subroutine that it should mask entries as long as I am still entering values in the Text box.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If AccessForm.PinEntry.Value = True Then
    AccessForm.PinEntry.PasswordChar = ""
ElseIf AccessForm.PinEntry.Value = False Then
    AccessForm.PinEntry.PasswordChar = "*"
Else
    AccessForm.PinEntry.PasswordChar = "*"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PinEntry_Change()
CheckBox1_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: It appears you are entering a password into `AccessForm.PinEntry` but evaluating if the value is a `Boolean` - `True` or `False`. Are you intending to evaluate if there is or is not a value in `AccessForm.PinEntry`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code will only mask when clicked is because you will only ever enter your final Else statement.  You are checking if the PinEntry (Textbox) has a boolean value of True or False, which it never will.

No need to call the checkbox click event when the text in the PinEntry Changes.  `Passwordchar` is a property that only needs to be set on the textbox when you want to enable or disable it. You just need to act when the Checkbox is clicked.

This code will show the pin if the checkbox is checked, and apply the mask if it is unchecked.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        PinEntry.PasswordChar = ""
    Else
        PinEntry.PasswordChar = "*"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Samuel Everson: my thanks for the help. The solution above solves it. My logic is not correct as you said and there is no need to call any function or place any code under PinEntry_Change() or CheckBox1_Click(). I am new to this paradigm of writing VBA which is all event-driven. I understand that the property .Value for CheckBox1 is what should be used. But I still don't understand why the code whilst working didn't  have a condition that was not the following: ```If CheckBox1.Value == True Then``` instead of ```If CheckBox1.Value Then```.

Comment: An if statement makes logical comparisons, evaluating it to a boolean value: True or False.  CheckBox1.Value is a boolean value, it is True when Checked, and False when Unchecked.  In other words, if the checkbox is checked it is saying `if true then...`  It is not wrong to write `if Checkbox1.value = true`, it just adds an unnecessary comparison for the computer to calculate: `if true = true then...` (Not that you would notice the difference with modern computer speeds).  If this answer solved your question please consider marking it as the correct answer.  :)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. And for earlier. I did not realize that you are the one who answered the question. I will definitely make it the correct answer. I need a little bit more reputation to make any answers as "Correct". I am sure I will be posting more problems as I still doing task-based activities and problems to grasp VBA. I will be returning to all questions and set the best answers to "Correct" :)